# Implementation of cons/pair

Tags: c, lisp, scheme

What are the options of implementing a Lisp's cons/pair in a low-level language such as C?

One common implementation is a struct consisting of fields **type**, **car** and **cdr**. I know that linked lists are not very efficient for storage, but the additional **type** filed makes it even worse.

I read on Wikipedia that [Lisp machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_machine) used to add additional bits to each word for type information. But what are the options for today's architectures (x86, ARM)?

Comment: Don't you basically want to implement a stack data structure?

Comment: @bitmask I guess behind the scenes a Lisp could use a stack or a vector instead of a list, depending on situation, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Halst, how could a linear data structure suffice? This is a *pair*, and if I remeber my lisp correctly this can even loop. So much of any type of graph is possible. I don't think that there is much of a possibility to have it as `struct` or `void*[2]` or something like that.

Comment: @JensGustedt I remember reading somewhere that modern Lisp compilers try to detect when a list could be substituted efficiently with a vector. Although it should be a proper list.

Answer (score 3):

Cons cells are just one type of data we need to represent in Lisp. Others are arrays or vectors. Strings. Characters. Numbers. Symbols. Records. Instances of Classes.

Not only Lisp Machines used tag bits. Most Lisp implementations use them.

Most Lisp implementations use just the bits inside each memory word. Various Lisp Machines differed in their number of bits per word. Symbolics 36** machines used 36 bit words. Symbolics Ivory used 40 bit words. TI Explorer used 32bit words. So Symbolics used an unusual word size and TI used a *normal* word size. Symbolics was able to address more memory with its 40bit CPUs - 16 GBytes. 8bits of a word were used for the tags. Symbolics also had various other optimizations in representing data (for example lists could be represented as *cdr-coded* vectors - this technique is not used in current Lisp implementations).

Most of today's CPUs are 32bit or 64bit architectures. That makes a Lisp cons cell then two of these words in size and the bits have to fit into these word sizes. A fixnum is smaller than 32bit or 64bit. A fixnum is an integer which fits into a word minus the tag bits. For larger integers the numbers need to be represented differently. Thus a full 64bit long number is not representable as a fixnum on an 64bit machine. Common Lisp provides information about these sizes. On my 64bit LispWorks the most positive fixnum is 1152921504606846975.

```
CL-USER > MOST-POSITIVE-FIXNUM
1152921504606846975
```

It would be unusual to waste extra memory for the tag bits. Most current Lisp implementations have to put the tag bits into the data word (32bit or 64bit). Lisp implementors have been working hard to make this as efficient as possible.

Comment: To add some details, the tag bits are usually at the least significant position, so object pointers are turned into normal pointers by zeroing the tag bits, assuming that the objects start at addresses aligned by 2^tagbits. Some implementations might use more than one tag for fixnums, e.g. all tags with a lower-bit 0  are fixnums, so it can use e.g. 31-bit fixnums on a 32-bit platform. JavaScript VMs might use NaN-boxing, as doubles are the norm there, not integers.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the `type` field with a tag in the *pointer*.

Combined with [NaN boxing](http://wingolog.org/archives/2011/05/18/value-representation-in-javascript-implementations) you can reduce each stack slot (and the `car` and `cdr` fields of your `cons` structure) to the size of a `double`.

You will still have the `malloc` overhead (one or two words) for each cons cell however.

Comment: Not necessarily; if you take the observation that cons cells are constant size, you can allocate big blocks of them with malloc, and use a simple bitmap to store which are in use and which are free. Then you only have one malloc overhead per block of cells. It's called a slab allocator.